# Regex that match functions name but not declarations in source code

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to find function names in source codes but not in function declarations. Let's say we have the following source code:

```
function foo()
{
 if ( ! foo5() )
  foo3(bar("string"), foo2());
 else
  foo3(bar("string"));
}

function foo4()
{
 if (!foo5())
  bar2(bar("string"), foo2());
 else
  bar2(bar("string"));
}
```

I want to extract `foo5`,`foo3`,`bar`,`foo2`,`bar2` but **not** `foo` and `foo4`

I tried the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/SL0BLT/1) with no luck

`(?<!function )(\w+)\(`

All words that have open parenthesis but not started with `function`

Comment: why vote to close!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<!function )(\b\w+)\(
```

As far as I can see it's working for your example.